# How to delete the first row of a CSV file using python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to delete only the first row (not the headers) of a CSV using Python.

I have tried many solutions using the `csv` module or `pandas` but nothing have worked for me yet. All the solutions either printed out the csv and didn't modify the original file.

And importantly, I do not want to print out or skip/ignore the first line, I want to **delete** it and save it to the original file, not creating another file.

Comment: Read the entire CSV into a Pandas dataframe, remove the first row of the dataframe, save the entire resulting dataframe to a CSV file with the same name as in your input file.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(...,skiprows=1)` ; `df.to_csv('new_file.csv',index=False)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
FILENAME = 'test.csv'
DELETE_LINE_NUMBER = 1

with open(FILENAME) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines() # Read csv file
with open(FILENAME, 'w') as g:
    g.write('\n'.join([data[:DELETE_LINE_NUMBER]] + data[DELETE_LINE_NUMBER+1:])) # Write to file
```

---

Original test.csv:

```
ID, Name
0, ABC
1, DEF
2, GHI
3, JKL
4, MNO
```

---

After run:

```
ID, Name
1, DEF
2, GHI
3, JKL
4, MNO
```

(deleted `0, ABC`)

Comment: Just added a `DELETE_LINE_NUMBER` constant so you can choose which line you want to delete (0 = headers, 1 = first row, etc.)

Comment: OP didn’t say what their CSV looks like, but this won’t work if the first line has line breaks as part of the data. I always recommend using Python’s CSV module to be fully compliant and safe when reading/writing CSV files.

Comment: Yeah, they didn't put it in the question, but they did comment `i havent put my example csv in the question but you actually used similar example csv as mine` so I think this is ok

Answer (score 2):

After reading the csv file as csv reader, next() will return each row in the file, so can be solved like this:

```py
import csv
csv_file_name= '<your_file_name>.csv'

file = open(csv_file_name)
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

# store headers and rows
header = next(csvreader)

# ignore first row 
next(csvreader)

# store other rows
rows = []
for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)

file.close()

with open(csv_file_name, 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # write the header
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write multiple rows
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: How would OP skip the first row, like they asked for? (Best answer so far, using CSV and next()… just need to get that requirement in).

Answer (score 1):

If your (CSV) file is small enough, read it into memory, remove the line and write it back.

No Pandas or even the `csv` module needed here.

```
# Read lines into list
with open("myfile.csv") as f:
    lines = list(f)

lines.pop(1)  # pop the second line out (assuming the zeroth line is headers)

# Write lines back into file
with open("myfile.csv", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

If your file is larger, don't read it all into memory, but filter it into a second file on the fly, then replace the first:

```
import os

with open("myfile.csv") as rf, open("myfile.csv.temp", "w") as wf:
    for i, line in enumerate(rf):
        if i != 1:  # Everything but the second line
            wf.write(line)

os.replace("myfile.csv.temp", "myfile.csv")
```

Comment: Using the CSV module for reading/writing CSV files is always better, safer, and more compliant than not. Why recommend avoiding an actual parser for a formally specified format? What’s to be gained by essentially writing an ad-hoc CSV parser?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that. It works if the file isn't too big

```py
# Read the data
with open("your file.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n")

# Remove the 1st line
del data[1]

# Save the data
with open("your file.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(data))
```